# Google Spreadsheet: How to display a value from the cell which is in the same column as the largest value in the other row

Tags: google-sheets

I've tried combination of MAX, HLOOKUP and CELL but it doesn't work. I want to display a name of the oldest person. In the following link you can find a screenshot of the example table.

[image of the example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmwTR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX(1:1, 1, MATCH( MAX(2:2), 2:2, 0) )
```

You specify a whole row by its number: 2:2

You find the MAX in that row: MAX(2:2)

You MATCH the found **maximum** in that **range**, **exactly**: MATCH( MAX(2:2), 2:2, 0)

This returns the number representing the offset of the row/column.

You access the contents of the cell with INDEX, specify the **range** in which you wish to access cells, the **row** offset beginning with one, the **column** offset beginning with zero: INDEX(range, row, column)

Comment: But what if there would be multiple matches? How I can display second or even third result?